# Date Transformation using Hive or sql

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

Premise: You have a table with one column, `original_date`, of datatype string:

```
ORIGINAL_DATE  
20190825 
20190826 
20190827 
20190828 
20190829 
20190830 
20190831 
20190901
```

Question: Write a SQL query to calculate two more columns – `end_of_week` - the date of the next Sunday from `original_date`. If `original_date` is already a Sunday, this field should be the same value `end_of_month` - the value of the end of month date An acceptable solution is one which works for any valid date in the string format of `original_date`. With end_of_month and end_of_week computed

```
ORIGINAL_DATE    END_OF_WEEK     END_OF_MONTH  
20190825    20190825    20190831 
20190826    20190901    20190831 
20190827    20190901    20190831 
20190828    20190901    20190831 
20190829    20190901    20190831 
20190830    20190901    20190831 
20190831    20190901    20190831 
20190901    20190901    20190930
```

Additional Info:

20190825 is a Sunday, so the `end_of_week` for that value is still that same date.

20190827 is a Tuesday, and the next Sunday is on 20190901

```
CREATE TABLE random_dates ( original_date VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL  ); 

INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190825'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190826'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190827'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190828'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190829'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190830'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190831'); 
INSERT INTO random_dates(original_date) values('20190901');
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
20190825    2019-08-25  2019-08-31 
 20190826   2019-09-01  2019-08-31 
 20190827   2019-09-01  2019-08-31 
 20190828   2019-09-01  2019-08-31 
 20190829   2019-09-01  2019-08-31 
 20190830   2019-09-01  2019-08-31 
 20190831   2019-09-01  2019-08-31
 20190901   2019-09-01  2019-09-30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT original_date,
CASE  DAYOFWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'))
WHEN 1 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 0 DAY)
WHEN 2 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 6 DAY)
WHEN 3 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 5 DAY)
WHEN 4 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 4 DAY)
WHEN 5 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 3 DAY)
WHEN 6 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
WHEN 7 THEN  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END AS END_OF_WEEK,
LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(original_date,'%Y%m%d')) AS END_OF_MONTH
FROM random_dates;
```

Comment: Can you give a little context? What is your code snippet doing (and why)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Hive:

```
with random_dates as (--this is your example dataset
select stack(8,
'20190825', '20190826', '20190827', '20190828', '20190829', '20190830', '20190831', '20190901'
) as original_date
)

select original_date,
       date_add(date_formatted, 6-days)  end_of_week,
       last_day(date_formatted)          end_of_month
  from       
      (
       select original_date, 
              regexp_replace(original_date,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3') date_formatted,
              pmod(datediff(regexp_replace(original_date,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3'),'1900-01-08'),7) days
         from random_dates
      )s
;
```

Result:

```
original_date   end_of_week end_of_month
20190825    2019-08-25  2019-08-31
20190826    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190827    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190828    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190829    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190830    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190831    2019-09-01  2019-08-31
20190901    2019-09-01  2019-09-30
```